# A for loop within a for loop to calculate CV values

Tags: r, for-loop, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to iterate values of 1 to 30 k-nearest neighbors and store each calculated CV value in a vector. I have an existing code written for k=1 but I believe I need a nested for loop for 1 to 30 k values.

```
AutoSd <- Auto %>%
mutate(weight.std = scale(weight),year.std = scale(year)) %>%
select(weight,year,weight.std,year.std,mpg)

y <- AutoSd$mpg
x <- AutoSd %>% select(weight,year)

nfolds=10; n = dim(Auto)[1]
groups = rep(1:nfolds,length=n)
set.seed(2)
cvgroups = sample(groups,n)
LOOCVpredictions = rep(NA,n)
k_vals = seq(1,30, by = 2)
cvgroups = 1:n; nfolds=n

for (iii in 1:length(k_vals)){ #I am trying to do the nested loop here but I'm not sure how to store each value for 1-30
  for (ii in 1: nfolds) {
    groupii = (cvgroups == ii) 
    train.x = x[!groupii,]
    train.x.std = scale(train.x)
    train.y = y[!groupii]
    test.x = x[groupii,]
    test.x.std = scale(test.x,
                    center = attr(train.x.std, "scaled:center"),
                    scale = attr(train.x.std, "scaled:scale"))
  predictions = knn.reg(train.x.std, test.x.std, train.y, k_vals)
  LOOCVpredictions[groupii] = predictions$pred
  }
}
CV = mean( (y - LOOCVpredictions)^2 )
```

Here is a general layout of what I am looking for

```
Outer loop: iterate from 1 to 30 for each value of k

       Inner loop: use the 10 training/test splits
              scale each training and test set
              use knn.reg with k = the value in the outer loop
              calculate the prediction from knn.reg and store it in a vector

     calculate CV(10) for the current value of k and store it in a vector
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding your problem correctly, therefore I made some very generic code to walk through 2 vectors, make a simple prediction vector, bind this in a nested list and calculate means over the prediction vectors and simplify the results to a list without the aditional nesting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

outer <- 1:4
inner <- 1:3

res <- list()

for (iii in 1:length(outer)) {
    resi <- list()
    for (ii in 1:length(inner)) {
        prediction <- c(iii, ii)
        resi[[ii]] <- prediction
    }
    res[[iii]] <- resi
}

purrr::map(res, ~.x %>% purrr::map_dbl(~mean(.x))) 

[[1]]
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0

[[2]]
[1] 1.5 2.0 2.5

[[3]]
[1] 2.0 2.5 3.0

[[4]]
[1] 2.5 3.0 3.5
```